# 0-1 Knapsack with Large Weights and Values: How much faster is recursive dp than iterative dp?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Suppose I wish to solve 0-1 knapsack but both weights and values of elements can get large. (`Weight[i] < 1e5 and Value[i] < 1e9`)

Also, number of items is `~2000` and size of knapsack is `~4e6`.

Obviously `dp[index][weight]` exceeds memory and time expectations.

However, somewhat magically memoization dp (values stored in `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`) works well. I can see why it may be bit faster: after all, in recursive dp, we compute only the states we need.

But, is it actually significantly faster? In other words, the usual computation requires `8e9` operations, but how much speedup can we expect, *on average*, by computing `dp` this way?

Since computing a state takes constant time, the question boils down to - how many *(expected / on average)* states can be there to compute? (normally it's `8e9`)

You can assume:

1. We use `std::unordered_map`.
2. Our hash function works well enough.
3. Recursive Overheads can be ignored.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the iterative version is slower if you can't implement it because it "exceeds memory"?  You really only need a 1-dimensional array `dp[knapsack_size]`, which is quite reasonable, and will compute at most 1.6e10 states -- about half a minute.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I know it's slower because I ran on my computer. Even after memory optimization you suggested, the recursive one runs in a few seconds on my computer and the iterative one doesn't.

Comment: Did you check to make sure they both produce the same answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case, the recursive version can compute nearly as many states as the iterative version.  Since you've implemented the recursive version without exceeding your available memory, you are pretty far from the worst case.

In special cases, the recursive version can be faster than the naive iterative DP.  For example, if all or most of your weights have a large common factor, then that factor will divide the number of states that need to be computed.  If you implement the iterative version so that it only considers accessible weights, then it will see this speed-up as well.

Comment: Yeah so that's my question - if the input is fully random (that is we are dealing with the average case and the input in non-pathological), is there some calculations we can do to predict the speedup we are expected to get?

Comment: With fully random inputs, you only have to consider about log(knapsack_size) objects before a large proportion of weights become accessible, so the speedup is not much for the sizes you've given.